# Get a DataTable Columns DataType

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, datagridviewcolumn

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();  
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(gridColumn1, typeof(bool)));
```

I was expecting the result of the below line to include info about the DataColumns Type (bool):

```
?dt.Columns[0].GetType()
```

Answer (score 99, accepted):

What you want to use is this property:

```
dt.Columns[0].DataType
```

The `DataType` property will set to one of the following:

```
Boolean
Byte
Char
DateTime
Decimal
Double
Int16
Int32
Int64
SByte
Single
String
TimeSpan
UInt16
UInt32
UInt64
```

[DataColumn.DataType Property MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype.aspx)

Comment: And any other type name, eg System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary

Answer (score 16):

You could always use `typeof` in the if statement. It is better than working with string values like the answer of Natarajan.

```cs
using System.Data;

if (dt.Columns[0].DataType == typeof(DateTime))
{
    //...
}
```

or using column name :

```cs
if (dt.Columns["yourColumnName"].DataType == typeof(DateTime))
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
dt.Columns[0].DataType.Name.ToString()
```

Comment: Please add more details about your answer e.g. explain why your code works etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can get column type of DataTable with **DataType** attribute of datatable column like below:

```
var type = dt.Columns[0].DataType
```

`dt`: DataTable object.

`0`: DataTable column index.

Answer (score -2):

```
if (dr[dc.ColumnName].GetType().ToString() == "System.DateTime")
```

Comment: Getting the type, then converting to a string to compare to seems a little redundant.